# Old community promotion ads still showing up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, caching, community-promotion-ads

[image: borky]

I can reliably reproduce this after several shift+F5s: the old Community Promotion Ads are still showing up (at least on Programmers.SE), from 2014, not the new ones from 2015.

Is this just another case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com? (It would have to be server-side, since even after manually disabling the cache I can reproduce this.) Or is it a bug? Oddly enough, that ad is the only one that I've seen after refreshing at least 25 times, which smells of a strange bug, but it could still just be a caching quirk.

Comment: Sort of a bug, but sort of not. The new ad meta post hasn't been hooked up to the display yet, so it's still working off of the old thread. I'll ask if it's supposed to be switched over already or if that's intentionally not done yet.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a bit of a grace period before the old ads go away, since the new posts only went up yesterday.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for catching this, but for the moment this is working as intended. The ads are still running off of the old 2014 meta posts for two reasons:

1. The new posts only went up a couple days ago and we normally wait a bit to have them pick up speed.
2. Holidays/vacations happened.

We should be switching over to the new ads sometime next week.

Comment: I'm happy that "Holidays/vacations happened.". Some things are more important than advertising.